# What is the need for the use of 'de' (or du) in the following sentences

Tags: grammaire

1) "C'est du mauvais francais" translates to "This is bad French". What is the need for "du"?

2) " Je fais du tennis" translates to "I play tennis". Again, what is the need for "du" ?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, it is a *partitive article*. It is needed when you mention an indefinite amount or quantity of an uncountable item. It has no equivalent in English: depending on the context, it may be translated as *some*, *any*, or would be left out.

> Je mange de la viande
>
> Je bois de l'eau
>
> Je fais du pain

In your 2 cases, even though these are not strictly speaking items you can count or measure, it is the same idea.

*C'est du mauvais français* expresses the idea that is some "piece" of bad French.
In the same way, you could say

> c'est de la mauvaise nourriture
>
> c'est de la mauvaise musique

*Je fais du tennis* is more idiomatic: when you do an activity and you use the verb *faire*, in French, this activity is seen as an uncountable item that you are producing:

> je fais du tennis
>
> je fais de la peinture
>
> je fais du bricolage
>
> je fais du shopping